# SparkPost sending e-mail Template

Tags: php, email, sparkpost

I am using **SparkPost PHP API** to send e-mail to recipient but I am facing this error. Currently I have set up all the necessary field but I still have problems with large e-mails. I can easily send small text but I'm having difficulties with large data.

> [{"message":"required field is missing","description":"At least one of 'text' or 'html' needs to exist in 'content'","code":"1400"}]

**My code is:**

```
for ($j = 0; $j < count($result1arr); $j++) {

    try {

        SparkPost::setConfig(["key" => "XXXXX"]);
        $results = Transmission::send(array(
                    "from" => "test@universityfood.co",
                    "html" => $resultarr['mailBody'],
                    "text" => $resultarr['mailBody'],
                    "subject" => $resultarr['subject'],
                    "recipientList" => $result1arr[$j]['groupName']
        ));

        $_SESSION['success_message'] = 'Email sended successfully to Recipient List with ID : ' . $data['recipients_id'];
        $qry = "DELETE  from mailQueue where mailQueueId={$result1arr[$j]['mailQueueId']}";
        $res = $conn->query($qry);
        $sql1 = "INSERT INTO sendMailHistory (schoolName,noOfMailSent) VALUES ('{$result1arr[$j]['originalGroupId']}','{$results['results']['total_accepted_recipients']}')";
        $result1 = $conn->query($sql1);

        $chc = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($chc, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sparkpost.com/api/v1/recipient-lists/{$result1arr[$j]['groupName']}");
        curl_setopt($chc, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($chc, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($chc, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($chc, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
        curl_setopt($chc, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            "Accept: application/json",
            "Authorization: XXXXX"
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($chc);
        curl_close($chc);
        header('Location: ../index.php');
        exit;
        return true;
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        echo $exception->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed your API key from the question, but you should delete that key and create a new one :/

Comment: What is the approximate size of the email that is failing? I assume everything else is the same between the small messages and the large emails?

Comment: Are you still having issues Bindesh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because `$resultarr['mailBody']` is not defined.

Are you sure the array `$resultarr` exists? If so, the `mailBody` element must be missing.

You may supply either a `text` portion or an `html` portion, or both. But if you supply neither you will get the error: `At least one of 'text' or 'html' needs to exist in 'content'`.

In this case neither are being supplied because `$resultarr['mailBody']` being undefined causes the `text` and `html` elements of the array to be undefined.

Comment: You should add some more information to make the answer more meaningful.

Comment: Thanks for your help string value which i pass in $resultarr['mailBody'] has some special characters which are causing trouble